# URL query parameters to dict python

Tags: python, parsing, url, query-string

Is there a way to parse a URL (with some python library) and return a python dictionary with the keys and values of a query parameters part of the URL?

For example:

```
url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98"
```

expected return:

```
{'ct':32, 'op':92, 'item':98}
```

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Use the [`urllib.parse` library](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98"
>>> parse.urlsplit(url)
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.org', path='/default.html', query='ct=32&op=92&item=98', fragment='')
>>> parse.parse_qs(parse.urlsplit(url).query)
{'item': ['98'], 'op': ['92'], 'ct': ['32']}
>>> dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(url).query))
{'item': '98', 'op': '92', 'ct': '32'}
```

The `urllib.parse.parse_qs()` and `urllib.parse.parse_qsl()` methods parse out query strings, taking into account that keys can occur more than once and that order may matter.

If you are still on Python 2, `urllib.parse` was called [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Answer (score 64):

For Python 3, the values of the dict from `parse_qs` are in a list, because there might be multiple values. If you just want the first one:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs
>>>
>>> url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98"
>>> query = urlsplit(url).query
>>> params = parse_qs(query)
>>> params
{'item': ['98'], 'op': ['92'], 'ct': ['32']}
>>> dict(params)
{'item': ['98'], 'op': ['92'], 'ct': ['32']}
>>> {k: v[0] for k, v in params.items()}
{'item': '98', 'op': '92', 'ct': '32'}
```

Comment: This is not unique to Python 3, Python 2 `urllib.parse_qs` also returns lists for the values. I specifically mention this in my answer, by the way, you may want to use [`urllib.parse_qsl()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl) instead and past the resulting list to `dict()` if you just want single values.

Comment: Seems like the difference with `parse_qls` is that since it returns a list of tuples, converting *that* to a dict will keep the **last** value instead of the **first**. This of course assumes there were multiple values to begin with.

Answer (score 19):

If you prefer not to use a parser:

```
url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98"
url = url.split("?")[1]
dict = {x[0] : x[1] for x in [x.split("=") for x in url[1:].split("&") ]}
```

So I won't delete what's above but it's definitely not what you should use.

I think I read a few of the answers and they looked a little complicated, incase you're like me, don't use my solution.

Use this:

```
from urllib import parse
params = dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(url).query))
```

and for Python 2.X

```
import urlparse as parse
params = dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(url).query))
```

I know this is the same as the accepted answer, just in a one liner that can be copied.

Comment: Parsing involves more than just splitting the string. You also need to handle URL encoding (including the `+`), and the `urllib.parse` also either raises or ignores errors for you as requested. I'm not sure why you'd want to reinvent this wheel when it is part of the standard library.

Comment: Small correction. It must be url[0:] not url[1:] . Otherwise it will leave first character.


dict = {x[0] : x[1] for x in [x.split("=") for x in 
    url[0:].split("&") ]}

Answer (score 7):

For python 2.7

```
In [14]: url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98"

In [15]: from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl

In [16]: parse_url = urlparse(url)

In [17]: query_dict = dict(parse_qsl(parse_url.query))

In [18]: query_dict
Out[18]: {'ct': '32', 'item': '98', 'op': '92'}
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree about not reinventing the wheel but sometimes (while you're learning) it helps to build a wheel in order to understand a wheel. :) So, from a purely academic perspective, I offer this with the caveat that using a dictionary assumes that name value pairs are unique (that the query string does not contain multiple records).

```
url = 'http:/mypage.html?one=1&two=2&three=3'

page, query = url.split('?')

names_values_dict = dict(pair.split('=') for pair in query.split('&'))

names_values_list = [pair.split('=') for pair in query.split('&')]
```

I'm using version 3.6.5 in the Idle IDE.

Answer (score 2):

```
from urllib.parse import splitquery, parse_qs, parse_qsl

url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98&item=99"

splitquery(url)
# ('http://www.example.org/default.html', 'ct=32&op=92&item=98&item=99')

parse_qs(splitquery(url)[1])
# {'ct': ['32'], 'op': ['92'], 'item': ['98', '99']}

dict(parse_qsl(splitquery(url)[1]))
# {'ct': '32', 'op': '92', 'item': '99'}

# also works with url w/o query
parse_qs(splitquery("http://example.org")[1])
# {}

dict(parse_qsl(splitquery("http://example.org")[1]))
# {}
```

Old question, thougt I'd chip in though after I came across this `splitquery` thingy. Not sure about Python 2 since I dont use Python 2. `splitquery` is a bit more than `re.split(r"\?", url, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

For `python2.7` I am using `urlparse` module to parse url query to dict.

```
import urlparse

url = "http://www.example.org/default.html?ct=32&op=92&item=98"

print urlparse.parse_qs( urlparse.urlparse(url).query )
# result: {'item': ['98'], 'op': ['92'], 'ct': ['32']}
```

Comment: Is there a way not to reconstruct the original url by say just removing the item.

Answer (score -1):

WSGI, python 2.7

**Code**

```
    import sys
    import json
    import cgi
    import urlparse

    def application(environ, start_response):

      status = '200 OK'

      method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
      args = urlparse.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
      m = args['mesg']

      x = {
      "input": m[0],
      "result": m[0].capitalize()
      }

      # convert into JSON:
      y = json.dumps(x)

      output = y

      response_headers = [('Content-type', 'application/json'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
      start_response(status, response_headers)
      print (sys.version_info)
      return [output]
```

**URL**

http:///echo.py?mesg=hola

**Response**

{"input": "hola", "result": "Hola"}

Answer (score -3):

You can easily parse a URL with a speciific library.

> Here is my simple code to parse it without any dedicated library.

(the input url must contain a domain name,a protocol and a path.

def parseURL(url):

```
seg2 = url.split('/')[2]    # Separating domain name
seg1 = url.split(seg2)[-2]  # Deriving protocol
print('Protocol:', seg1, '\n')
print('Domain name:', seg2, '\n')
seg3 = url.split(seg2)[1]   #Getting the path; if output is empty,the there is no path in URL
print('Path:', seg3, '\n')

if '#' in url:  # Extracting fragment id, else None
    seg4 = url.split('#')[1]
    print('Fragment ID:', seg4, '\n')
else:
    seg4 = 'None'
if '@' in url:              # Extracting user name, else None
    seg5 = url.split('/')[-1]
    print('Scheme with User Name:', seg5, '\n')
else:
    seg5 = 'None'
if '?' in url:              # Extracting query string, else None
    seg6 = url.split('?')[-1]
    print('Query string:', seg6, '\n')
else:
    seg6 = 'None'

print('**The dictionary is in the sequence: 0.URL 1.Protocol 2.Domain name 3.Path 4.Fragment id 5.User name 6.Query string** \n')

dictionary = {'0.URL': url, '1.Protocol': seg1, '2.Domain name': seg2, '3.Path': seg3, '4.Fragment id': seg4,
              '5.User name': seg5, '6.Query string': seg6}  # Printing required dictionary
print(dictionary, '\n')

print('The TLD in the given URL is following: ')
if '.com' in url:           # Extracting most famous TLDs maintained by ICAAN
    print('.com\n')
elif '.de' in url:
    print('.de\n')
elif '.uk' in url:
    print('.uk\n')
elif 'gov' in url:
    print('gov\n')
elif '.org' in url:
    print('.org\n')
elif '.ru' in url:
    print('.ru\n')
elif '.net' in url:
    print('.net\n')
elif '.info' in url:
    print('.info\n')
elif '.biz' in url:
    print('.biz\n')
elif '.online' in url:
    print('.online\n')
elif '.in' in url:
    print('.in\n')
elif '.edu' in url:
    print('.edu\n')
else:
    print('Other low level domain!\n')

return dictionary
```

if **name** == '**main**':
url = input("Enter your URL: ")
parseURL(url)

```
#Sample URLS to copy
# url='https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2068026323275211&set=a.269104153167446&type=3&theater'   
# url='http://www.blog.google.uk:1000/path/to/myfile.html?key1=value1&key2=value2#InTheDocument'      
# url='https://www.overleaf.com/9565720ckjijuhzpbccsd#/347876331/'
```

Comment: The TLD detection part might not work for URLs such as this one: `https://www.info.ca/`