# Transform multiple values from url to json in Django

Tags: python, json, django, url

I have this URL:

```
http://example.com?variable=1&variable=2&a=text
```

I want to transform those values to JSON.

I have tried:

```
data = json.dumps(request.GET)
```

But I get `{"variable": "2", "a": "text"}`

It seems to work for single values but not for multiple ones.

How can I get all the values from the URL transformed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL query parameters to dict python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `urlparse` module can do this for you.

**Results:**

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

o = urlparse('http://example.com?variable=1&variable=2&a=text')
qs = parse_qs(o.query)
print(qs)
```

**results:**

```
{'variable': ['1', '2'], 'a': ['text']}
```

Comment: For some reason I have this error(anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py in urlsplit, line 182): 'function' object has no attribute 'find'
So I can't try right now...Looking for a solution to that error.

Comment: solved but i got this: {'a': ['1', "2'>>"], 'search_txt': ['T']}

Comment: It seems to work. The reason why i got that result seems to be request.get_full_path. It wil return something like: <bound method WSGIRequest.get_full_path of <WSGIRequest: GET '?variable=1&variable=2&a=text'>>

Note:I am using django

Comment: **Solved**

`qs = parse_qs(request.META['QUERY_STRING'])
data = json.dumps(qs)`

result: `{"variable": ["1", "2"], "a": ["text"]}`