# how to split Python requests get with parameter?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need help on how do I split the parameter from an url in when using python requests `get`.

Assuming I have this url

```
https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages?data=%7B%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D
```

and I did `requests.get` by

```
_get = requests.get("https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages?data=%7B%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D", headers={"Authorization":"MyToken 1234abcd"})
```

I checked with `_get.url` and it return

```
u'https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages?data=%7B%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D'
```

Then I tried with the following to split the parameter

```
url = "https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages"
query = {"data[]":[{"limit_count":100, "limit_size":100}]}
headers = {"Authorization":"MyToken 1234abcd"}
_get = requests.get(url, params=query, headers=headers)
```

`_get.url` return the following result

```
u'https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages?data%5B%5D=limit_count&data%5B%5D=limit_size'
```

without `100` and `10000`

In this kind of url --> `https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages?data=%7B%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D`, how exactly to split its parameter?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: thanks, it is a good reference but I prefer to use the `requests` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for:

```
data={"limit_count":100,"limit_size":1000}
```

as your query params.

Unfortunately, `requests` will not flatten this nested structure, it treats any `Iterable` value as multiple values for the key, e.g. your nest dictionary is treated like:

```
query = {'data': ['limit_count', 'limit_size']}
```

Which is why you don't see `100` and `1000` in the end result.

You will need to flatten it into a string. You can use `json.dumps()` to create the required string (double quotes vs. single quotes, compact). Then `requests` will do the required URL encoding, e.g.:

```
In []:
data = {'limit_count': 100, 'limit_size': 1000}
query = {'data': json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))}
request.get('http://httpbin.org', params=query).url

Out[]:
'http://httpbin.org/?data=%7B%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs
import requests
url = "https://blabla.io/bla1/blas/blaall/messages?data=%7B%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D"
query = urlsplit(url).query
params = parse_qs(query)
headers = {"Authorization":"MyToken 1234abcd"}
_get = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use the `requests` library to parse URLs.

You use that to handle the requests. If you want a URL parser, use `urllib.parse` instead.