# “Unknown String Format”-Error when parsing URLs in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I want to extract dates from a pandas dataframe column of URLs.
Here is my code:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import pandas as pd

    df_results["URL"] = df_results["URL"].astype("str")  # String conversion
    URLs = df_results["URL"].tolist()                    # List creation
    for URL in URLs:                                     # Loop through list
        date = dparser.parse(URL,fuzzy=True)             # Parse date
        print date                                       # Print date
```

However, I receive a `ValueError: Unknown string format`:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-fd55da2e8e1e> in <module>()
     69 
     70 
---> 71 df_results = parse_URL(df_final) # parse 2
     72 
     73 print df_results.head()

<ipython-input-23-fd55da2e8e1e> in parse_URL(df_final)
     51     URLs = df_results["URL"].tolist()
     52     for URL in URLs:
---> 53         test = dparser.parse(URL,fuzzy=True)
     54         print test
"_")

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1180         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1181     else:
-> 1182         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1183 
   1184 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    557 
    558         if res is None:
--> 559             raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
    560 
    561         if len(res) == 0:

ValueError: Unknown string format
```

I assume that the URLs are stored as some sort of hyperlink. However, df.info() shows an `object` dtype for `URL`.

**Q1: How to covert a pandas column of URLs to raw string dtype?**

**Q2: How to extract dates from a pandas dataframe column of URLs and save them to a new column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for `NaT` for unparseable datetimes, but first [parse url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43628262/2901002):

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs

df = pd.read_csv('data_sample.csv')

f = lambda x: pd.Series({k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(urlsplit(x).query).items()})
df_results = df['URL'].apply(f)
df_results["checkinDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df_results["checkinDate"], errors='coerce')
df_results["checkoutDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df_results["checkoutDate"], errors='coerce')
print (df_results)
```

Comment: this leaves a column full of 'NaT'

Comment: Can you add data sample?