# Pandas Add column from splitting existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas. I am working on some sample data.

```
My sample data is
'Col1'    'Col2'   'Query'
10000       101     $name=XXX&#age=18&#mark=100  
10001       102     $name=YYY&#age=17&#mark=95
```

This is my CSV data. I want to load this into a data frame as below,

```
'Col1'    'Col2'   'Query'                       $name    #age   #mark
10000       101     $name=XXX&#age=18&#mark=100  XXX       18     100
10001       102     $name=YYY&#age=17&#mark=95    YYY       17     95
```

What I've tried so far is,

```
querydf = pd.DataFrame(rundf['Query'].str.split('&').tolist())
```

I have created a data frame by splitting the column `'Query'` by `'&'`. But After that How can I split those list by `'='` and add the first item as a header?

Comment: Incidentally `split` supports regex, try `df.Query.str.split(r"&|=", expand=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Create list of dictionaries for each row and call `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = []
for v in df['Query']:
    out = {}
    for x in v.split('&'):
        a, b = x.split('=')
        out[a] = b
    L.append(out)

print (L)
[{'$name': 'XXX', '#age': '18', '#mark': '100'}, 
  {'$name': 'YYY', '#age': '17', '#mark': '95'}]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L))
print (df)
    Col1  Col2                        Query #age #mark $name
0  10000   101  $name=XXX&#age=18&#mark=100   18   100   XXX
1  10001   102   $name=YYY&#age=17&#mark=95   17    95   YYY
```

Another solution for list `L` is parsing query by [`parse_qs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43628262):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

L = [{k: v[0] for k, v in dict(parse_qs(v)).items()} for v in df['Query']]
print (L)
[{'$name': 'XXX', '#age': '18', '#mark': '100'}, 
  {'$name': 'YYY', '#age': '17', '#mark': '95'}]
```