# Equivalent regular expression to extract link using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to randomly explore Webscraping through python.I have link of google search results page. I used url lib to extract all the links which are present in the GOOGLE SEARCH RESULT PAGE. From that parsed page of google I am extracting all possible anchor tags with the help of Beautiful Soup library. So now I have lots of links. Among those I want to pick selected links which matches my required pattern.
Example I want to pick all such lines:
This is one of the many links that got parsed. But I want to narrow down the result of the links which are like this

```
/url?q=http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiYwOKe1r7hAhWUf30KHcHUBkMQFggUMAA&usg=AOvVaw39cIJ0T8_CAQMY8EkSWZJl
```

And among such picks I need to extract only this part

```
http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/
```

I tried this and this

```
possible_websites.append(re.findall('/url?q=(\S+)',links))
possible_websites.append(re.findall('/url?q=(\S+^&)',links))
```

Here's my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
tags = soup('a')
possible_websites=[]
for tag in tags:
    links = tag.get('href', None)
    possible_websites.append(re.findall('/url?q=(\S+)',links))
```

I want to use regular expression to extract the required text part. I am using Beautiful soup module to extract the HTML data. In short this is much of a reguar expression problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get 

http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/

from 

/url?q=http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiYwOKe1r7hAhWUf30KHcHUBkMQFggUMAA&usg=AOvVaw39cIJ0T8_CAQMY8EkSWZJl

through regular expression

Comment: Please read question more carefully so that you can understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need a regex, use `q=(.*/)&` otherwise go with [Ry-'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563024/797495), i.e.:

```
import re
u = "/url?q=http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiYwOKe1r7hAhWUf30KHcHUBkMQFggUMAA&usg=AOvVaw39cIJ0T8_CAQMY8EkSWZJl"
m = re.findall("q=(.*/)&", u)
if m:
    print(m[0])
    # http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/
```

[image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcwWkf/1)

Comment: Yes its working and I understand how but can you please tell what is wrong with 

possible_websites.append(re.findall('/url?q=(\S+^&)',links))

Comment: or
possible_websites.append(re.findall('/url?q=(\S+)',links))

Comment: `?` is a special character in regex. You need to escape it if you want a literal question mark, like so: `\?`. Also `re.findall` takes a single string as its second argument, not a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not regex, but I’d use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse):

```py
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

url = urlparse('/url?q=http://avadl.uploadt.com/DL4/Film/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiYwOKe1r7hAhWUf30KHcHUBkMQFggUMAA&usg=AOvVaw39cIJ0T8_CAQMY8EkSWZJl')
qs = parse_qs(url.query)

print(qs['q'][0])
```

Comment: You didn't read the question maybe. I have already parsed my link. That's how I got this link

Comment: @EXODIA: You parsed your HTML to get a URL. This parses the URL to get the value of the `q` parameter. Try running it.

Comment: @QHarr: I pasted it wrong, sorry. Should be `qs['q']`, not `qs.q`.