# How to parse url arrays in python?

Tags: python, html, url, flask

I want to parse an array of objects in a url into Python. 
I have tried using a url like this:

```
url = "?query[]=item1&query[]=item2&query=item3"
```

and `request.args.get('query')` returns None 
I have also tried using a url like this:

```
url = "?query=item1&query=item2&query=item3"
```

and `request.args.get('query')` only returns item 1.
What is the best way parse the url into a list of items?

Comment: maybe duplicated with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url)

Comment: I'm not sure if you need "how to parse url" or "how to generate url with many values in one variable which flask could parse correctly". it is two different problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `getlist()`

```
print(request.args)
print(request.args.getlist('query'))   
print(request.args.getlist('query[]'))
```

For `?query[]=item1&query[]=item2&query=item3"` it gives

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('query[]', 'item1'), ('query[]', 'item2'), ('query', 'item3')])
['item3'] # query
['item1', 'item2'] # query[]
```

For `?query=item1&query=item2&query=item3"` it gives

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('query', 'item1'), ('query', 'item2'), ('query', 'item3')])
['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] # query
[] # query[]
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is almost definitely the wrong way to do this, it should still work.

```
parsed = [x.split("=")[1] for x in url[1:].split("&")]
```

I would recommend looking at some of the other answers to use a library with more robust and consistent capabilities.