# Regexp: Find string contains 'a', 'b' and doesn't contain 'c'

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

> ```
> someURL&screenName=anyScreen&category=/any/EndPoint&carousel=/Catalog/something
> ```

can be many strings with &category and &carousel parameters or without.

I need two regexps:

1. find string that contains '&screenName=anyScreen' also contains '&category=' and contains '&carousel=' parameters

simply did it in this way:

> `.*&screenName=anyScreen.*&category=.*&carousel=.*$`

maybe you will explain some better way how to find it. However, this ^^ works fine for me.

I faced a problem with a second one regexp:

2. find string that contains '&screenName=anyScreen' also contains '&category' and doesn't contain '&carousel'

I tried this:

> `.*&screenName=anyScreen.*&category=.*((?!&carousel=).)*$`

As I know ((?!&carousel=).)*$ should work as Negative Lookahead and should exclude string with this word
but this regexp doesn't work for me. What I'm doing wrong ?

p.s. will use regexp in python

Comment: Rather than using regex for this, have you considered just [using `urllib.parse` to extract the query string args from the url into a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python), and then checking that the resulting keys are or are not in the dict, which is much simpler than using regex?

Comment: ^ This. Your current regex wouldn't work if the order of the parameters was switched around.

Comment: thanks a lot will take a look!

Comment: do you need two regex expressions or can you write a function for this? If the order of the parameters can vary in the url string, you might want to do three separate regex expressions that look for the presence/absence of each substring

Comment: The order of parameters won't be changed. 'category' and 'carousel' parameters may be in string or may not be. 
I get a list of strings from api and need to get in first case string with category and carousel parameters. In another case with category but without carousel. And then use it for other actions.
So, was thinking to use foreach and find expected string using regexp