# Getting Query Parameters as Dictionary in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I spent last month learning Flask, and am now moving on to Pyramid and FastAPI.  One of the requirements for my application is to get all the query parameters in a dictionary (there are multiple combinations, and I can assume all keys are unique and have a single value)

In Flask, for request like **GET /?foo=1&bar=2** I can get the foo and bar parameters from a dictionary like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def root():
     if 'foo' in request.args:
         return f"foo was provided: {request.args['foo']}", 200
     else:
         return "I need your foo, fool!", 400
```

I cannot figure out how to do the same easily in FastAPI / Starlette.  Best solution I've come up with is to manually build the dictionary by splitting up request.query_params:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
@app.get("/{path:path}")
def root(path, request: Request):

    request_args = {}
    if request.query_params:
        for _ in str(request.query_params).split("&"):
            [key, value] = _.split("=")
            request_args[key] = str(value)
```

It certainly seems there should be an easier way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: Why do you have two `@app.get` and why is your path `{path:path}`?

Answer (score 18):

This is simple, just isn't documented very well.  The **Request** class has an attribute called **[query_params](https://layer77.net/2021/05/05/getting-web-server-variables-and-query-parameters-in-different-python-frameworks/)**. It's a [mulitdict](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/), but can easily be converted to a standard dictionary via the dict() function:

```
def root(path, req: Request):
    request_args = dict(req.query_params)
```

Comment: Indeed, `req.query_params` is perhaps the easiest way to get it.

Comment: Be careful with blindly casting `request.query_params` to a dict. If you have, as the HTTP spec allows, multiple query parameters with the same key, it will only return the first key/value pair.

Thus,
`app?id=foo&id=bar`
will only give you a dict with:
`dict(req.query_params) => { 'id': 'foo' }`

It's much safer to iterate through them, or re-parse as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/1183198

Answer (score 0):

And to access any received JSON payload as dictionary (Flask-style, without the need to pre-define all dictionary keys), use the type hint `Dict`:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Union

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root(path, request_dict: Union[List,Dict,Any]=None):
    return request_dict # a dict
```