# How to get query params in fast api from POST request

Tags: python, fastapi

Client might send multiple query params like:

```
# method = POST 
http://api.com?x=foo&y=bar
```

I need to get all the query params and `extract` it as a string `x=foo&y=bar` from the POST request.

Is there a way to do this on `fast api`? I could not find it on their docs.

#### NOTE :

We are `not` sure of the names of the params before hand.

Comment: You can get the request URL and parse the query string by yourself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Query Parameters as Dictionary in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67393319/getting-query-parameters-as-dictionary-in-fastapi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending how you want to use the data, you can either use `request.query_params` to retrieve a immutable dict with the parameters, or you can use `request.url` to get an object representing the actual URL. This object has a `query` property that you can use to get the raw string:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return request.url.query

 
uvicorn.run(app)
```

This returns the given query string `/?foo=123` as `foo=123` from the API. There is no difference between a POST or GET request for this functionality.