# How to get query parameters including keys with blank values in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, query-string, starlette

I want to handle a use case, where a key is passed to the `GET` request's query parameters, but **without** a value.

For example (request through Postman):
[image: Postman Request]

In the case above, `name` is passed as a `key` but no `value` is set.

I tried using:

```
request.query_params
```

but, it doesn't seem to get the `name`, if the value is blank.

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve query parameters from a `request` object, one could use `request.query_params`, which returns a [`starlette.datastructures.QueryParams`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/85d35737c7053bee489c438467b18a9108b23b93/starlette/datastructures.py#L385) object that is actually an [`ImmutableMultiDict`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/85d35737c7053bee489c438467b18a9108b23b93/starlette/datastructures.py#L253) with the query parameters. Another way is to use `request.url.query`, which returns the raw query string, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804). Both approaches should also return keys with blank values in the query string.

##### Example

```py
@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return request.query_params
```

**Test URL**

```
http://localhost:8000/?x=foo&y=bar&z=
```

**Result**

```json
{"x":"foo","y":"bar","z":""}
```

One could retrieve values for specific keys the same way as in a standard `dict`:

```py
x = request.query_params["x"]
```

As noted earlier, `request.query_params` would return an immutable multidict—one could confirm that by using `print(type(request.query_params))`—and thus, if one would like to convert the result into a standard dictionary, they could do that using the `dict()` function:

```py
params = dict(request.query_params)
```

### Note

In a scenario where you expect a `list` of values for a specific key, and may appear multiple times in the URL, using `request.query_params` or `dict(request.query_params)` to get a dictionary of every key-value pair in the query string wouldn't work as expected. For instance, `/?foo=2&foo=10&bar=7` would return `{"foo":"10","bar":"7"}` instead of `{"foo":["2","10"],"bar":"7"}`. In that case, you may consider following an approach similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804), using [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs). In order to have keys with blank values included as well, you should set the `keep_blank_values` flag to `True`, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

> The optional argument `keep_blank_values` is a flag indicating whether
> blank values in percent-encoded queries should be treated as blank
> strings. A `true` value indicates that blanks should be retained as
> blank strings. The default `false` value indicates that blank values
> are to be ignored and treated as if they were not included.

##### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    q_params = parse_qs(request.url.query, keep_blank_values=True)    
    d = dict((k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0]) 
                for k, v in q_params.items())

    return d
```

**Test URL**

```
http://localhost:8000/?foo=2&foo=10&bar=7&z=
```

**Result**

```json
{"foo":["2","10"],"bar":"7","z":""}
```

On a side note, if the query parameters are known beforehand (not arbitrary) but not required, one could always declare them as [Optional parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters) in an endpoint (see [Query Parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) documentation). Related answers on how to define query parameters in a FastAPI endpoint can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070110/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74759329/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74536449/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804).

Comment: yeah, this seems the only way to properly deal with variable number of query parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `?name` is a possible URL query parameter that you might get without a value, you could declare it as optional in the handler function's parameter and then check for `is not None`. This example is adapted from the [Optional parameters doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters):

```py
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: str, name: str | None = None):
    if name is not None:
        return {"item_id": item_id, "name": True}
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

NOTE: you have to declare it as `str`, not `bool`, since otherwise `pydantic` will raise a [bool_parsing error](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.5/errors/validation_errors/#bool_parsing), since `bool` args only allow for a [limited set of values](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/types/booleans/).