# Pydantic Custom Data Types can't be optional in FastAPI route

Tags: python, fastapi, optional-parameters

Following the Pydantic [custom data types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#custom-data-types) instructions, I've created a type which attempts to get strings from a single comma-separated string like:

```
"foo,bar,baz" -> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

It works fine:

```py
class CommaSeparatedString(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.split_on_comma

    @classmethod
    def split_on_comma(cls, v: str | None):
        if not v:
            return None

        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise TypeError("String required")

        return [item.strip() for item in v.split(",")]


@app.get("/")
def applications_index(
    strings: CommaSeparatedString | None,
):
    print(strings)
```

But FastAPI doesn't honour the optional nature of the `strings` param.

It complains about missing fields when I make a request without `strings` in the querystring:

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'strings'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]
```

Comment: Please have a look at the "Note" section in the link provided above, as well as at the "About Optional Parameters" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804). In short, "the most important part to make a parameter optional is the part: `= None`".  Since you are dealing with arbitrary query parameters, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe You need to add default value, so Your code would look like that:

```
class CommaSeparatedString(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.split_on_comma

    @classmethod
    def split_on_comma(cls, v: str | None):
        if not v:
            return None

        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise TypeError("String required")

        return [item.strip() for item in v.split(",")]


@app.get("/")
def applications_index(
    strings: CommaSeparatedString | None = None,
):
    print(strings)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a real facepalm moment for me. Yes, I should have set `= None` to make it work. Thanks for pointing this out.