# how to save search input query from url

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a way to have my url search value carried over from one view to another.

For example. if I have the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/search_result/posts?search=harry`
It would use my `SearchPostView` view to display all filtered posts with the authors name being `harry`. However on that same page I want users to be able to click a button that would take them to a page where it would show all users on the site with the name `harry`.

My problem stems from when I try to use redirect the user to the page of filtered users, I dont understand how I could carry over the `?search=harry` url value to my `SearchUserView` view.

A good visual example is how github implements this.
[image]
in the url they have `search?q=harry` where it would show the filtered repo page with `harry` in the name. If I were the click on `Users` button on the side navbar, it would then show the url being `search?q=harry&type=users` with the filtered users page

Although I'm not trying to completely copy github, I essentially just want to know how to keep that url query in different views. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: @Goion that looks really promising, I'll give it a try!