# how to parse query string parameters in python?

Tags: python, rest

I am working on a REST API and using python. say for a get request ( sample below),
I am assuming , anyone who makes a call will URL encode the URL, what is the correct way to decode and read query parameters in python?

'https://someurl.com/query_string_params?id=1&type=abc'

```
import requests
import urllib

  def get():
        
    //parse query string parameters here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: Read the documentation? e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=url%20decode

Comment: @SvenEberth - thanks. do i need URL decoding , in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to split a URL and get the query parameters:

```
import urllib.parse

url='https://someurl.com/query_string_params?id=1&type=abc'

url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)

print( f"{url_parts=}" )

query_parts = urllib.parse.parse_qs(url_parts.query)

print( f"{query_parts=}" )
```

Result:

```
url_parts=ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='someurl.com', path='/query_string_params', params='', query='id=1&type=abc', fragment='')
query_parts={'id': ['1'], 'type': ['abc']}
```

Documentation is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=url%20decode