# How can I retrieve the code generated in Strava API auth?

Tags: python, strava

I have some auth url from Strava API:

1st URL:

```
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=71724&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Fauthorization&approval_prompt=auto&response_type=code&scope=read_all%2Cprofile%3Aread_all%2Cactivity%3Aread_all
```

that makes the user to accept terms etc.
After the acceptance of this, I would need to get a numeric code from the string generated.

For example, I need to get this number from this string:

```
code to get: "503eb7de3b98e70d267c0a6be7a06ed1af0da132"
```

from 2nd URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorization?state=&code=503eb7de3b98e70d267c0a6be7a06ed1af0da132&scope=read,activity:read_all,profile:read_all,read_all
```

How can I make python to get that code automatically after the acceptance of the user? Do I need to use requests library? In that case, how would it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: the problem is not to parse the url, is how to make python go to that url first and then parse the second url to get the code (without opening browser with webbrowser library)

Comment: You wrote "how to get this number from this string" - using for example `urllib.parse` is how. If you are actually asking something different, please clarify your question - or if you are asking this *and* something different, too, then this question is too broad and you should focus it on one specific problem.

Comment: Apologies for that, actually you solved me the url parsing problem. Now I'd like to know how to get the 2nd URL in order to parse it afterwards as you said. Is there any specific function in urllib for that?