# How to invoke the url and get the query parameter in python

Tags: python

I have tried to invoke the url with query string  and get the parameter as token .
Example url : 199.168.99.99:8898/?token=gakamab182662.

I want to get the token value and i want to pass the token value in another java application method .
Example :
In python
'''Str token = get the token from url .
Call the java class method .
Mycalss abc = new Mycalss () .
abc.method1(token)
'''

Please let me know how can I do this step in python .

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code so that we can help you. We won't write your whole code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of regular text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)