# how to converate post data into variables that i can use in python

Tags: python, webserver

I've been trying to find a way to convert POST data from a request
when i print the data this is what i get `b'message=sdfa&arent=gfsdgd&btn3=pressed'`
I've tried different ways to get it ive used replace but i realized that wasnt gonna work i saw that flask does something like this but id have to rewrite all my code using it
i am using http.server and i was wondering if i could have the output formatted like json so were i could use something like value["message"] and it would give me what is inside the message

this is my first time using stack overflow so im sorry if i dont make sense or look stupid

Comment: Are you trying to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)? It's not clear at all what your question actually is without further context, as your question contains elements from all over the place.

Comment: @metatoaster
thank you ive been trying to figure this out for hours
,yes im sorry i dont really have any reason why i wrote it so badly.
how do i say that the question was answered

Comment: Usually it would be good to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by providing a code example on the problem you are actually trying to solve.  Also your input that you want to convert is in fact formatted as a query parameter string, which if appeared as part of some POST data returned by the server's response wouldn't change that fact.

Answer (score 0):

question was answered by a comment

There is a library that formats a link into practically a json file

the library is called urllib
big thanks to metatoaster